# JCrop with React using custom script to load the jquery Object: TypeError: a is undefined

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jcrop

I have made the following application: https://github.com/pc-magas/reaqct-jcrop

And I have the following component that I want to use the jcrop in it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from './MyJquery.js';
import Jcrop from 'jcrop';


class JCrop extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            'imageToCrop':props.imageToCrop,
            'imageHtmlElement':null
        }
    }

    comonentDidMount() {
        $("#img").Jcrop();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <img id="img" rel={ (rel) => {this.setState({imageHtmlElement:rel})} } src={ this.state.imageToCrop } />
        )
    }
}

export default JCrop
```

And I also created the `./MyJquery.js` in order to apply the Jquery Object to the window:

```
import $,{jQuery} from 'jquery';

window.jQuery = jQuery;
export default $
```

But when I run the application via npm run I get the following error:

> TypeError: a is undefined

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the `window.jQuery` does not containt the proper object. It must have the `$` objext instead of the jQuery one. So the `./MyJquery.js` should be:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

window.jQuery = $;
export default $
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should change `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`.
In your case the `#img` element is not exist yet when you are trying to `Jcrop`.